# Guava.jar in Spring boot maven project - why it is added even none of its apis are consumed in my project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, guava

I just want to make my jar size smaller. Many of the jars added by maven dependencies are unnecessary, one of them is guava.jar and I am not able to understand its purpose in the project.

What functionality will not work if this jar is removed?

Comment: Assuming it's maven read about maven dependency:tree. Not necessarily it's your code using guava. But maybe the other libraries you use, may be using guava. And this plugin will tell you the right set.

Comment: spring-boot doesn't use it by default, probably it's a dependency of some of your libraries

Comment: I understand, but thats my query - what is the functionality of this jar which will not work if I remove it. I found thats its used by Swagger, but if I exclude it, what will be the impact?